# prevent automatic redirect to AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1 query string

Tags: asp.net, webforms

When I try to connect to my site [tebim](http://tebim.ir)
a query string with key"AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport" and value "1" is added to my site's url.

My site is asp.net 4.5 web application.

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is inside your application,but please try to pay attention for [Routing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551(v=vs.100).aspx) . This is something that helps to have cool urls.